# Getting ERROR: "Failed to resolve: localbroadcastmanager" in Connecting Android project to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to connect Firebase To android and I have errors when I sync the project. I have the latest version of google repository and I have added the needed dependencies to Project level build.gradle and app level build.gradle.

Below is my app-level Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ecommerce"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2' 
  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And my project-level gradle :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0' 
     }
  }

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
 }
 } 
 task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
   }
```

Comment: can you please share project level gradle also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I immigrated to androidx. I also added below line to my app-level Gradle and it worked:

```
   implementation 'androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0'
```